# Cloud SDK installer fails to install on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, gcloud

When running the Cloud SDK installer (or `gcloud components update`) on Windows Server 2008 R2, the installion process fails and the following error is thrown (from python.exe):

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe". 
>   Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. 
>   Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

To successfully install/update the gcloud command-line tool on Server 2008 R2, the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) is essential to include necessary libraries.

It can be installed from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582

If you're on or updating to 64-bit python, you'll need to install the 64-bit version of the redistributable instead:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092